# How to apply conditions in mysqli query

Tags: php, sql, html, css, mysqli

I want to apply conditions with my query like i want to interchange one column's value to another column. Here is my query and now i am not getting how to apply

```
mysqli_query($connect, "
    select 
        user_pro.User_No, 
        user_pro.Fist_Name, 
        user_pro.Last_Name, 
        user_pro.Designation, 
        user_pro.Profile, 
        user_pro.ProfileDP, 
        user_fndrst.Frnd_SNo, 
        user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender, 
        user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver, 
        user_fndrst.Rqst_Status 
    from 
        user_profile INNER JOIN user_fndrst ON user_pro.User_No = user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender 
    WHERE 
        user_fndrst.Rqst_Status='1' AND 
        user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' 
    ORDER BY Frnd_SNo DESC
");
```

Here "user_pro" table contains user's details, "user_fndrst" table contains user's friend request status and $user_id is user's logined id. Here I want that IF user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' THEN  user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver value change to user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender.

For this I have stuck with user friend request status fetching from table "user_fndrst".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you trying to update a column or trying to select?

Comment: If you are using this exact query you have to add user_pro alias in from section of query. " From user_profile as user_pro "

Comment: Actually I want to change one column's value to another column on a condition. Like   IF user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' THEN CHANGE user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver value  to user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender.

Comment: Sorry it's user_pro not user_profile here i entered by mistake...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query has some problems. Use this:

```
SELECT 
    user_pro.User_No, user_pro.Fist_Name, user_pro.Last_Name, user_pro.Designation, user_pro.Profile, user_pro.ProfileDP, user_fndrst.Frnd_SNo, user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender, user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver, user_fndrst.Rqst_Status 
FROM
    user_profile user_pro
    INNER JOIN user_fndrst ON user_pro.User_No = user_fndrst.Rqst_Sender 
WHERE 
    user_fndrst.Rqst_Status='1' AND user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' 
ORDER BY 
    user_fndrst.Frnd_SNo DESC
```

Comment: Sorry this is not my problem this query will give output in descending order but I want that from table 'user_fndrst' column  'Rqst_Receiver' value change to column 'Rqst_Sender' value on condition user_fndrst.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id'.